# Interface 'App\HasMediaConversions' not found

Tags: laravel

still messing around with Spatie's Medialibrary package for laravel and i'm getting tons of problems, now that all the code on the view it's ok and the code of the model too, I've encountered a problem from part of the package and i actually need some help over here, i don't know if i should re-install it or something... here is the error message:

```
Interface 'App\HasMediaConversions' not found
```

and the code of the user model is this one:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMediaTrait;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\Interfaces\HasMedia;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\User as EloquentUser;

class User extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User implements HasMediaConversions
{
use Notifiable, HasMediaTrait;
```

has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: maybe try `HasMedia` instead ? cause that's what you are importing `Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\Interfaces\HasMedia`

Comment: Hey, tried but guess what, does not work. I checked my PHPStorm and it indicates me that there is a `Undefined namespace Interfaces` and `Undefined class HasMediaConversions` or `Undefined class HasMedia` i followed up the documentation as it needs to be and well, not working at all....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable; 
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMediaTrait; 
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMedia;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\User as EloquentUser;

class User extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User implements HasMedia {

use Notifiable, HasMediaTrait;
```